# In a 2-dimensional array of integers, how can we place a new integer at a completly random spot in the 2-d array?

Tags: java, arrays, 2d

Specifically, if we create a method that will generate this integer and place it at a random spot in the array.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
static void placeRandomly2D(int[][] arr, int limit) {
// generates value [0...limit) half-interval and places it into the 2D array arr
//    at random position; limit must be positive
    Random rand = new Random();
    int value = rand.nextInt(limit);
    int pos1 = rand.nextInt(arr.length);
    int pos2 = rand.nextInt(arr[pos1].length);
    arr[pos1][pos2] = value;
}
```

And, just in case, version for 1-dimensional array:

```
static void placeRandomly1D(int[] arr, int limit) {
// generates value [0...limit) half-interval and places it into the 1D array arr
//    at random position; limit must be positive
    Random rand = new Random();
    int value = rand.nextInt(limit);
    int pos = rand.nextInt(arr.length);
    arr[pos] = value;
}
```

Comment: This seems to only handle a 1-d array.

Comment: you should extract the creation of a `new Random()` to somewhere outside the method, since the randomness of a freshly seeded RNG is not guaranteed.

Comment: @Vogel612: Well, in theory since for `Random` constructor without argument system time is taken as the seed, you would expect different seeds in different calls, hence guaranteed random results between different calls. But I suppose, if `placeRandomly1D()` method is called several times within the same millisecond, it will generate identical values (since `Random` instances created will have the same seed). Is that what you mean?